# Simple calculator using Arguments

Tags: c

Hi im newbie to C and im trying to code a simple arg calculator but i got weird results:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int res;
    int boo = 0;
    int fstnum = atoi (argv[1]);
    int scnnum = atoi (argv[3]);
    char op = argv[2][0];

    if (argc != 4) {
        printf ("Invalid parameters !\n");
        printf ("Try [Num] [Opr] [Num] for example : 1 * 1 \n");
    }
    else {
        switch (op) {
            case '+':
                res = fstnum + scnnum;
                break;
            case '*':
                res = fstnum * scnnum;
                break;
            case '-':
                res = fstnum - scnnum;
                break;
            case '%':
                res = fstnum % scnnum;
                break;
            case '/':
                if ((scnnum = 0)) {
                    printf ("Error ! Can't devide by zero");
                    boo = 1;
                } else {
                    res = fstnum / scnnum;
                }
                break;
            default:
                boo = 1;
                printf ("Invalid Operator Try again!\n");
        }
    }

    if ((boo = 0)) {
        printf ("The result is :  %d", res);
    }

    printf ("%d\n", fstnum);
    printf ("%c\n", op);
    printf ("%d\n", scnnum);

    return 0;
}
```

after running the program as this `$ argcalc 1 * 1` this what i got :

Invalid Operator Try again!

```
1

a

1
```

I still dont understand why it takes `"*"` as an `"a"`?

Answer (score 4):

1. The `if (argc != 4)` should be at the start before you even consider using the arguments.
2. The use of `*` is interpreted by the shell. Do `argcalc 1 '*' 1` instead.

Comment: At the start of the program print out `argc` and the values in `argv`

Comment: i think the problem is in the operator cause everything else works as it should !

Comment: everything works, but it won't print the result, the number 1 problem is your if statement of boo, it is always false, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Never assign in the if statement if you are new to C, that's why some suggests put the right side of the operator first, like this:

```
if (0 == boo) {
    printf("The result is : %d\n",res);
}
```

this way the compiler will explicitly warn you when you mistake == for =.

Also, put the check of argc at the beginning of main.

Third, * will be interpreted by the shell as a wildcard, so make sure use '*' on command line. The 'a' you saw is because this.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Aside from your shell interpretation of `'*'` as a wildcard and your *assignment* instead of *conditional* expressions, there are several other improvements that can be made.

Generally when you are providing error information you will want to write to `stderr` instead of `stdout`, e.g.

```
    fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid number of parameters\n"
                     "usage: num [+*-%%/] num (e.g. 1 * 1 )\n");
```

There is no need for `boo`. You are not going to scare the machine into exiting. You can simply `return 1;` at that point (an exit code of `0` generally representing *success*, and anything else a numeric code for an *error condition*.

There is no need for highly nested code checking for `if (argc != 4)... else...`. You can simply perform the check for the correct number of arguments and `return` or `exit` at that point.

Putting the pieces together, you can tidy things up with something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc != 4) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid number of parameters\n"
                         "usage: num [+*-%%/] num (e.g. 1 * 1 )\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int res, fstnum = atoi (argv[1]), scnnum = atoi (argv[3]);
    char op = *argv[2];

    switch (op) {
        case '+': res = fstnum + scnnum; break;
        case '*': res = fstnum * scnnum; break;
        case '-': res = fstnum - scnnum; break;
        case '%': res = fstnum % scnnum; break;
        case '/':
            if (!scnnum) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: divide by zero\n");
                return 1;
            } else res = fstnum / scnnum; break;
        default:
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid operator\n");
            return 1;
    }

    printf (" %d %c %d = %d\n", fstnum, op, scnnum, res);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ for i in + \* - % /; do ./bin/rfmt 8 "$i" 4; done
 8 + 4 = 12
 8 * 4 = 32
 8 - 4 = 4
 8 % 4 = 0
 8 / 4 = 2
```

Comment: thnx a lot i always make the mistake of "==" :/ 
one more thing plz why char op = *argv[2] instead of char op = argv[2][0]

Comment: when i do 1 '*' 1 it takes 1 and ' and 1

Comment: try `1 \* 1`. That is a windows/DOS issues, and I apologize, I have no clue how to prevent expansion other that escaping the character `\*` or attempting to single-quote it `'*'`. Let me know if either works.

Comment: Found it what works is "*" ;)
 but what about  char op = *argv[2] instead of char op = argv[2][0]

Comment: It is the exact same thing. `argv[2][0]` is the same as `*(argv[2]) + 0)` (as any 2D index `a[i][j]` in pointer form is `*(*(a + i) + j)`). You are just dereference the address to the first character which is what?? The first character `:)` Or, think of it this way, `char *string = argv[2];`, now for the first char in `string` it is simply `*string`.